Graphics Setting in Android Emulator is greyed out
I want to run Android Studio and Android Emulator in my Azure VM D3V4.
I want to use hardware graphics for better performance.
The option to choose in "Emulator Perfomance / Graphics " section is greyed out.
When I try to set this using powershell command .\emulator -avd my_app gpu -host I get the following errors :

please update the Emulator to one that supports features : "Vulkan"
Feautre control is requesting a non existing feature
Your GPU Drivers may have a bug
cannot add library vulkan-1.dll failed


